# Mac OS Mojave downgrade PHP 7.3 to 7.2.14

Tags: apache, macos-mojave, php-7.2, php-7.3

I have installed PHP 7.2.14 with brew.

```
brew install php@7.2
```

On CLI I have already the 7.2.14 version, but not on Apache.
What should I do, so I can remove 7.3 from my Mac and use only 7.2.14

Answer (score 2):

you need to run

```
  brew link php@7.2
```

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:

```
  brew link --overwrite php@7.2
```

To list all files that would be deleted:

```
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run php@7.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP version in your CLI has nothing to do with the version you have on your Apache module.

You need to disable/enable the right modules in apache in order for the right php version to take affect.

For enabling/disabling a mod, you have this nice helper commands:

```sh
a2enmod <MOD_NAME> // Enable a mod

a2dismod <MOD_NAME> // Disable a mod
```

This one is not tested, but you should be able to do:

```sh
a2dismod php7.3

a2enmod php7.2
```

*P.S*

Not sure the apache helper commands are available in mac so you can do it directly through the `httpd.conf` file.

checkout `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and make sure the right modules are loaded.

Hope it helps.
Good luck :)

Comment: when i ran `a2dismod php7.3` `a2enmod php7.2` from terminal. I get `-bash: a2enmod: command not found` Any tips?

Comment: This commands are available in linux usually, try to open your apache configuration file and set your modules manually. (don't forget to restart the service when you'r done,)

Comment: oh the question is about Mojave MacOs. Can i somehow change the default php being used everywhere (maybe except in apache server.) I have a docker image running linux but i install libraries through composer on my mac then pass the files to the docker. So i need the php versions to match in mac and my docker image